# maven archetype suggestion for Java EE ear project with spring 3.x, logback etc

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-archetype

Below is what I am looking for. The closest archetype i found is [mesir](http://code.google.com/p/mesir/) but it is not updated with latest spring 3.0.5 release so looking if there are other alternatives.

**MUST have**

1. ear
2. ejb module
3. web module with jsf 1.2 and facelets configured
4. root spring ctx at ear level
5. web module will have the child spring app ctx

**NICE to have**

1. logback or slf4j configured
2. PrimeFaces configured for JSF
3. Hibernate 3.x that is JPA 1.0 compatible
4. jBPM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative, you may want to consider creating your own archetype using `maven-archetype-plugin`:

- http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/

Using `mvn archetype:create-from-project` you can do it from your customized project, which you can create in the first place by using the archetype that suits your needs as much as possible and then adding the things that are missing or reconfiguring as necessary.

Here are some tutorials:

- http://code.google.com/p/jianwikis/wiki/HowToCreateMavenArchetypeFromProject
- http://code.google.com/p/krank/wiki/CodeGeneratorAgain
- http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-archetypeng/creation.html
- http://www.bluesunrise.com:8080/webcontent/rproxy/maven_apache/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/create-multi-module-project.html

Take a look at `appfuse-basic-jsf`, link:

- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List

In fact, take a look at AppFuse itself:

- http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home

However, I still think you would need to tweak it if you want a one-click solution, though this seems like a very good start.

Comment: thank you. i want to use that as the last option. I am wondering if there are any out of the box solutions

Comment: Check the edit - not sure it's going to be 100% what you need, but certainly should be a good start.